# Understanding relations between model view and controller

Tags: model-view-controller

I went through a lot of readings about MVC and what each of these does is more or less clear. What I haven't understood yet is how they relate. I mean, I know about these relationships

[image: mvc relationships]

but how are they implemented? What happens in an MVC framework?

I also have a few questions:

- I read that [a view can't be coupled with the controller](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/77637), in other words it can't have a controller object inside, but then how does it use the proper controller if a view is supposed to trigger something in it?
- How can the model update the view if its unique job is to represent data?
- Is the business logic inside the controller or the model? I have read conflicting points of view

Comment: You have to implement something at least. Data doesn't do anything if it is just data. You have to implement functions to retrieve the data from where is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic explination of MVC would be that you have each of the 3 layers.

**Model**

- This contains your data. i.e database or set of classes.

**View**

- This displays data to the user i.e your HTML page.
- Contains controls for user interaction.

**Controller**

- All access to data should go through this layer. i.e load data from your data source(model) and save data to your data source.
- Carries out any data manipulation before saving or loading.

This create a separation of concerns theoretically allowing you to change anything in either layer without the other layer knowing or caring making for far more maintainable and readable code.

In practice this can become more complicated depending on how you wish to access data and display it although the basic principles still apply, occasionally meaning that each part of MVC pattern could be made up of smaller parts.

In terms of implementing it a good example would be ASP.Net MVC http://www.asp.net/mvc. the following could be a simple implementation of displaying some data via MVC using C#.

**Model (C# class)**

```
public class Person{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    return View(new Person() { FirstName = "Person", LastName = "1" });
}
```

**View (Index.cshtml)**

```
@model Person

Full name: @Html.Raw(Model.FirstName + " " + Model.LastName)
```

This would output onto the web page

Full name : Person 1

Please forgive me for any syntax errors, not tested.

More detailed post: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm